# How to Retrieve Distinct Users and Their Categories Using Sequelize ORM in Node.js?

Tags: sql, mysql

I am trying to fetch a specific number of distinct users along with all the categories they have selected using Sequelize ORM in Node.js. Below is the query generated and executed by Sequelize:

```
SELECT
  `User`.*,
  `userCategories`.`id` AS `userCategories.id`,
  `userCategories`.`category_id` AS `userCategories.categoryId`,
FROM
  `users` AS `User`
  LEFT OUTER JOIN `user_categories` AS `userCategories` ON `User`.`id` = `userCategories`.`user_id`
  AND (`userCategories`.`deleted_at` IS NULL)
WHERE
  (
    `User`.`deleted_at` IS NULL
    AND (
      AND `userCategories`.`category_id` IN ('129', '203')
      AND `User`.`country_id` IN (1)
      AND `User`.`is_blocked` = false
    )
  )
ORDER BY
  `updatedAt` DESC
LIMIT
  10
OFFSET 1;
```

I have set a limit of 10 in the query, but the problem arises when users have multiple categories associated with them, leading to less than 10 distinct users being returned in the result. I need to obtain exactly 10 distinct users along with all the categories they have selected.

How can I adjust the query or use Sequelize methods to ensure I get 10 distinct users and their associated categories in the result? Your help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this in two stages.  First, identify the users that meet your criteria:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  `User`.`id`
FROM `users` AS `User`
INNER JOIN `user_categories` AS `userCategories` ON
  `User`.`id` = `userCategories`.`user_id`
  AND `userCategories`.`deleted_at` IS NULL
WHERE
  `User`.`deleted_at` IS NULL
  AND `userCategories`.`category_id` IN ('129', '203')
  AND `User`.`country_id` = 1
  AND `User`.`is_blocked` = false
ORDER BY
  `updatedAt` DESC
LIMIT
  10
```

Then, wrap in an outer SELECT to return the rows that you want for those specific users:

```
SELECT
  `User`.*,
  `userCategories`.`id` AS `userCategories.id`,
  `userCategories`.`category_id` AS `userCategories.categoryId`,
FROM
  `users` AS `User`
  INNER JOIN `user_categories` AS `userCategories` ON
    `User`.`id` = `userCategories`.`user_id`
    AND `userCategories`.`deleted_at` IS NULL
WHERE
  `userCategories`.`category_id` IN ('129', '203')
  AND `User`.`id` IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT
      `User`.`id`
    FROM `users` AS `User`
    INNER JOIN `user_categories` AS `userCategories` ON
      `User`.`id` = `userCategories`.`user_id`
      AND `userCategories`.`deleted_at` IS NULL
    WHERE
      `User`.`deleted_at` IS NULL
      AND `userCategories`.`category_id` IN ('129', '203')
      AND `User`.`country_id` = 1
      AND `User`.`is_blocked` = false
    ORDER BY
      `updatedAt` DESC
    LIMIT
      10
  )
```